# Without using the Jordan-Hölder theorem, show the following.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am not sure how to prove the following. I am practicing for an exam in a few months time, and found this from a past paper in my university which unfortunately doesn't come with solutions.

> $G$ is a finite group. Let $A$ be a nontrivial proper normal subgroup of $G$ such that $A$ and $G/A$ are simple groups. Without using the Jordan-Hölder theorem, prove that there cannot be a chain of subgroups $\{e\} \not\subseteq B \not\subseteq C \not\subseteq G$ with $B \triangleleft C$ and $C \triangleleft G$.

So we have $A \triangleleft G$ and $A$, $G/A$ are both simple. But is there a way to use this to show the result above..? Without using the theorem stated of course...

Help is very much appreciated, thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there were such a chain. Since $C\cap A$ is normal in $A$ either $C\cap A=1$ or $C\cap A=A$.

If $C\cap A=1$, then $C=C/(C\cap A)\cong CA/A\lhd G/A$ is normal in $G/A$ forcing $CA/A=G/A$.  But now, $B\cap A=1$, so $B\cong BA/A\lhd G/A$ a contradiction.

If $C\cap A=A$, then $C$ contains $A$ and, since $C/A\lhd G/A$, we must have $C=A$. But, now $B\lhd C=A$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

As $A$ is simple, and $A \cap B \triangleleft A$, we have either $A \le B$, or $A \cap B = 1$.

In the first case, $B/A \triangleleft G/A$, so since $G/A$ is simple
    either $B = A$ or $B = G$. In neither case there is room for $C$.

In the second case, $A B$ is a normal subgroup properly containing $A$ (or if you prefer $A B / A$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $G / A$), so since $G/A$ is simple, we have $A B = G$.

So $G/ B \cong A$ is simple, and once more there's no room for $C$.